# PHP Authentication class for Twitter and Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, twitter, oauth

I'm looking for a simple PHP class that supports Twitter and Facebook authentication. I don't need to access their respective API's or post anything. just simple, painless, basic auth.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe janrain coud fit you if you don't have enough traffic or you are able to pay some bucks on this

http://www.janrain.com